# Xslt и объединение тэгов с общим предком

Tags: xml, веб-программирование, xslt

Добрый день!

xml1 -> xslt -> xml2
все, на самом деле просто.

xml1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1251" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="t06.xsl" ?>
<source>
<L2_VFI>
    <vpn_id>14575</vpn_id>
    <vfi_name>01/IPZX/600633-14575</vfi_name>
    <L2_VFI_NEIGHBORS>
        <neighbor_address>65.19.105.1</neighbor_address>
    </L2_VFI_NEIGHBORS>
</L2_VFI>
<L2_VFI>
    <vfi_name>01/KEXN/100021-11529</vfi_name>
    <vpn_id>11529</vpn_id>
    <L2_VFI_NEIGHBORS>
        <neighbor_address>65.19.105.1</neighbor_address>
    </L2_VFI_NEIGHBORS>
    <L2_VFI_NEIGHBORS>
        <neighbor_address>65.19.105.17</neighbor_address>
    </L2_VFI_NEIGHBORS>
</L2_VFI>
```

</source>

xml2:

```
    <L2_VFI>
    <vpn_id>14575</vpn_id>
    <vfi_name>01/IPZX/600633-14575</vfi_name>
    <L2_VFI_NEIGHBORS>
        <neighbor_address>65.19.105.1</neighbor_address>
    </L2_VFI_NEIGHBORS>
</L2_VFI>
<L2_VFI>
    <vfi_name>01/KEXN/100021-11529</vfi_name>
    <vpn_id>11529</vpn_id>
    <L2_VFI_NEIGHBORS>
        <neighbor_address>65.19.105.1</neighbor_address>
        <neighbor_address>65.19.105.17</neighbor_address>
    </L2_VFI_NEIGHBORS>
</L2_VFI>
```

Использовалось такое преобразование:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1251" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version = "1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="L2_VFI">
<L2_VFI>

<xsl:for-each select="./*">
<xsl:if test="name(.)!='L2_VFI_NEIGHBORS'">
     <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>

<L2_VFI_NEIGHBORS>
<xsl:for-each select="L2_VFI_NEIGHBORS">

<neighbor_address><xsl:value-of  select="neighbor_address"/></neighbor_address>

</xsl:for-each> 
</L2_VFI_NEIGHBORS>

</L2_VFI>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Опытным путем установлено, что

> name(.)!='L2_VFI_NEIGHBORS

Найдет и внутренний тэг

> <\neighbor_address>

но ведь он вложенный, почему это работает? То есть его вложенность никак не учитывается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select="./*"` ищет непосредственных детей, дальше `name(.)` проверяется у них, и никакой иерархии там не будет. Попробуйте просто вывести результат для

```
<xsl:for-each select="./*">
  <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

будут перечислены тэги на одном уровне вложенности.
А вот `copy-of select="."` копирует тэг с иерархией, да.